# After chrome 69 update, flex box is creating issues in layout

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox

After chrome 69 update, flex box is creating issues in layout. The children of flex box pop out and is displaced towards top.

Comment: That's what I thought. I'm on a project using Vue / Vuetify, and `<v-divider>` suddenly take a huge amount of height due to the `flex: 1 1;` property.

Comment: This post was specific to the major impact on page layouts which was caused after updating to version 69 of chrome browser.

Comment: I removed flex-basis and it looks good again

Answer (score 2):

The trick is in the order or css display properties. So not everyone will come across this issue.

When we provide multiple properties for flex,chrome 69 demands us to give in a specific order.

"display: flex" should be after "display: -webkit-box"

Correct code

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: flex;
```

Code that produces bug

```
display: flex;
display: -webkit-box;
```

Comment: Placing the W3C unprefixed property last (after the prefixed versions) is standard practice. It is always recommended.

Comment: True. But if the order is different, its causing a major issue in the layout in chrome browser after it got updated to version 69. Many people would have affected and sitting without out a clue. This post was to help them.

Comment: Doesn't the latter just completely override?

Comment: Yes, but it is okay if that happens. `display: flex;` is the new property so its always good to override `display: -webkit-box;` with it. Browsers which requires `display: -webkit-box;` doesn't support  `display: flex;` so there wont be any override happening.